# Converting Certificate Signing Request to type cryptography.x509.base.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder to be ready for the signature

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, cryptography, x509

Step 1. I have generated a certificate signing request (csr) using the `cryptography` library.

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization


csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder().subject_name(x509.Name([
        # Provide various details about who we are.

        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"US"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"California")
    ])).add_extension(
        x509.SubjectAlternativeName([
            # Describe what sites we want this certificate for.
            x509.DNSName(u"mysite.com"),
        ]),
        critical=False
    )
```

```
type(csr) = cryptography.x509.base.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder
```

Step 2. Then I signed the certificate

```
cert = csr.sign(private_key, hashes.SHA256())
```

It now has the type:

```
type(cert) = CertificateSigningRequest
```

Step 3. The csr needs to be serialized, and the data can be written to a file to be saved or sent over the network

```
serialized = cert.public_bytes(
        serialization.Encoding.PEM
    )
```

type:

```
type(serialized) = bytes
```

Save the certificate

```
with open('cert_name.cert', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(serialized)
```

The issue arises when I need to read the certificate for another signature.

```
with open('cert_name.cert', 'rb') as f:
    load_cert = f.read()
```

```
type(load_cert) = byte
```

I guess, as in step 2, the `load_cert` needs to be of type `cryptography.x509.base.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder` to be signed, then, as in step 3, it will be serialized to be saved again.
How could I convert the `load_cert` to type `cryptography.x509.base.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder` to be ready for the signature.      Or Does anyone have an alternative to the process described here ?

Comment: `CertificateSigningRequestBuilder` is a factory class. It is not something that is read from a file. A signed CSR is a certificate, not a CSR, and when you read it from a file you are reading a certificate, not a CSR. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user207421 is my question a bit clear now ? Basically, I would like to read the certificate, re-sign it and save it. The read certificate is of type `bytes` which is correct, as it was converted to `public_bytes` before saving. However, to sign the certificate, we need to have it as a type `cryptography.x509.base.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder`. Hence, how could I read the certificate and convert it to a type ready for the signature ?

Comment: A lot of things don't make sense here. The purpose of a CSR is to convey the entity information to be used in a *single, unique* certificate to a certificate authority so they can create a certificate. There's no point to reusing a CSR because certificates should be unique. Also, you aren't saving your CSR, you're saving a public key, and you cannot re-create the CSR from the public key.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you are trying to sign a CSR multiple times, it should be signed once by you and then verified by a CA who will give you a certificate. [This tutorial](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/tutorial/) might clear things up for you.

To deserialise your CSR you should do something like:

```
with open('cert_name.cert', 'rb') as f:
  data = f.read()
load_cert = cryptography.x509.load_pem_x509_csr(data)
```

and you can verify that the deserialised CSR already has a signature with:

```
load_cert.is_signature_valid
```

Comment: Thank you @Stanley. I understand your comments and those of others. I should save the csr, load it, then sign and save the certificate(signed). Do you have an idea of how to save the `csr` generated in `step 1`, then load it, and then sign it as in `step 2`, and finally save it ?